# Create a service to repeat functions in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to write a service that simulates a polling functionality. My code is the following:

```
app.service('poller', ['$timeout',

    function($timeout) {

        return ({
            poll
        })

        function poll(e) {
            $timeout(function() {
                poll(e);
            }, 5000);
        }
    }
]);
```

When I inject it in my controller I try to use it like this:

```
poller.poll($scope.getNewMessages());
```

The weird thing is that it's only called once. Also when I try to use console log in the service like `console.log(e)` I get undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @charlietfl it's ES6 valid syntax. It's shortcut for `({poll:poll})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass function as value to the poller function and you need to call the function:

```
app.service('poller', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {

        return ({
            poll
        });

        function poll(e) {
            e();
            $timeout(function() {
                poll(e);
            }, 5000);
        }
    }
]);

poller.poll($scope.getNewMessages);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Might I ask why should I call the function inside the poller without the parenthesis?  `poller.poll($scope.getNewMessages)`

Comment: You're passing the function to poller and it become `e` argument and you call it inside the poller. If you add parenthesis it will call before the poller and the result will be passed as `e` argument.